# Why is my toString() printing toString class instead of my overriden method?

Tags: java

```
Question test = new Question();

useranswer = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
   "What is the Result?" + "\n" + test.toString() ));
```

my toString in question class

```
public String toSting() {
    return "" + firstNum + " " + operator + " " + secondNum + " = ";
}
```

why am I getting "getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())" format for my call to toString  instead of my overriden toString() in my Question class?

Comment: public String toSting() {
  return "" + firstNum + " " + operator + " " + secondNum + " = ";
 }

Comment: `toSting()` is not the same as `toString()`.

Comment: wow i'm dumb. Thanks.

Comment: In the future, please include all pertinent code.

Answer (score 8):

`toSting()` is not the same as `toString()`.

- Always add the `@Override` annotation before your method overrides.
- In the future for similar questions, always include pertinent code.

e.g.,

```
@Override  // don't forget this!
public String toString() {
    // code that returns a String
}
```

Comment: Well, that stung ... sorry :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer: ouch.